# How do I remove the colon from a form element's title - D7?

Tags: forms

I've hunted high and low for what generates this colon. I've looked in the`theme_form_element_label` function and at the `#title_display` attribute in the form api, but I cannot see how to override it. It must come from somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well easiest solution is to use [this](https://drupal.org/project/colectomy) module . But I am not sure you would be interested to install a module for this small task.

If not you need to do the following steps:

1. You need to copy the field.tpl.php to your theme folder.
2. Now in the template file you can find the code that outputs the colon.
3. Please remember to clear the cache.